# Как переносить текст на другую строку, как только он не помещается в контайнер?

Tags: вёрстка, html

Всем привет, скажите как сделать так, у меня есть контейнер:

```
<div id = "text">
<p>
бла бла бла тут типо тектс
</p>
</div>
```

И сделать так что, если вдруг будет длинное предложение, то чтобы текст не уходил за рамку этого div'a а просто перенёсся на другую строку? Я пробовал уже overflow, но он не помогает, включаю scroll или auto, он всё равно в линию всё делает, если пишу hidden то вообще текст обрезается. А как сделать чтобы он переносился?

Вот сама проблема:

[image]

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap

Comment: Вот спасибо большое! Отлично всё работает! :=)

Comment: word-wrap разрывает и по частям переносит на другую строчку оченьоченьдлинныепредлинныеслова, к вашим "длинным предложениям" отношения не имеет, разве что это предложение состоит только из одного длинного слова

Comment: можно посмотреть еще http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [word-wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

Answer (score 0):

Ширину задайте элементу `"div"` - `<div style="width: 300px">..`

Comment: Нет не помогло.